# How to avoid duplicates when joining multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

The table contain three records, see below the temporary table :

```
Declare @TimeStamp table (Id int, SalesMan_ID int, Module_Cdoe varchar(50),Time_In varchar(10),Time_Out varchar(10))

Insert into @TimeStamp values
(1,13524,'Analysis','1:30pm','1:40pm'),
(2,12543,'Analysis','2:10pm','2:30pm'),
(3,12543,'Analysis','3:10pm','3:30pm')


;with cteBase (Seq,Module_Cdoe) as(
    Select 1,'Photo' union all
    Select 2,'Survey' union all
    Select 3,'Merchand'
)
Select id=Row_Number() over (Order By Time_In,SalesMan_id,Seq)
      ,SalesMan_id
      ,b.Module_Cdoe
      ,Time_In
      ,Time_Out
 from @TimeStamp A
 Join cteBase B on (A.Module_Cdoe='Analysis')
 Order By 1
```

From the above query the result is :

```
id  SalesMan_id Module_Cdoe Time_In Time_Out
1   13524       Photo       1:30pm  1:40pm
2   13524       Survey      1:30pm  1:40pm
3   13524       Merchand    1:30pm  1:40pm
4   12543       Photo       2:10pm  2:30pm
5   12543       Survey      2:10pm  2:30pm
6   12543       Merchand    2:10pm  2:30pm
7   12543       Photo       3:10pm  3:30pm
8   12543       Survey      3:10pm  3:30pm
9   12543       Merchand    3:10pm  3:30pm
```

But I need like see below:

```
id  SalesMan_id Module_Cdoe Time_In Time_Out
1   13524       Photo       1:30pm  1:40pm
2   13524       Survey      1:30pm  1:40pm
3   13524       Merchand    1:30pm  1:40pm
4   12543       Photo       2:10pm  2:30pm
5   12543       Survey      2:10pm  2:30pm
6   12543       Merchand    2:10pm  2:30pm
```

(OR)

```
id  SalesMan_id Module_Cdoe     Time_In Time_Out
1   13524       Photo           1:30pm  1:40pm
2   13524       Survey          1:30pm  1:40pm
3   13524       Merchand        1:30pm  1:40pm
4   12543       Photo           3:10pm  3:30pm
5   12543       Survey          3:10pm  3:30pm
6   12543       Merchand        3:10pm  3:30pm
```

So what is the query to achieve my expectations?

Comment: do you want to show the earlier times or the later times. better to specify one or the other. If you're not concerned with them, do you need them? if not, you can just use grouping

Comment: I need the later times

Comment: update the question to specify this then, and change the id's to match the later rows in your expected output

Comment: @AlexandarR  OK, a small twist from the original.  I see ANALYSIS is gone,  Is the "anchor" now PHOTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, this is just a small twist on the original.

```
Declare @TimeStamp table (Id int, SalesMan_ID int, Module_Cdoe varchar(50),Time_In varchar(10),Time_Out varchar(10))
Insert into @TimeStamp values
(1,13524,'Analysis','1:30pm','1:40pm'),
(2,12543,'Analysis','2:10pm','2:30pm'),
(3,12543,'Analysis','3:10pm','3:30pm')


;with cteBase (Seq,Module_Cdoe) as(
    Select 0,'Analysis' union all
    Select 1,'Photo' union all
    Select 2,'Survey' union all
    Select 3,'Merchand'
)
, cteDistPop as (
    Select Distinct 
           SalesMan_Id
          ,Time_In  =  Max(Time_In)
          ,Time_Out =  Max(Time_Out)
     From  @TimeStamp
     Group By SalesMan_Id
)
Select id=Row_Number() over (Order By Time_In,SalesMan_id,Seq)
      ,SalesMan_id
      ,b.Module_Cdoe
      ,Time_In
      ,Time_Out
 from cteDistPop A
 Cross Join cteBase B 
 Order By 1
```

Returns   -- **Not clear on "Analysis" In or Out.  Either way you control that from within cteBase**

```
id  SalesMan_id   Module_Cdoe   Time_In Time_Out
1   13524         Analysis      1:30pm  1:40pm
2   13524         Photo         1:30pm  1:40pm
3   13524         Survey        1:30pm  1:40pm
4   13524         Merchand      1:30pm  1:40pm
5   12543         Analysis      3:10pm  3:30pm   <<-- Notice Later Date 
6   12543         Photo         3:10pm  3:30pm
7   12543         Survey        3:10pm  3:30pm
8   12543         Merchand      3:10pm  3:30pm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
Declare @TimeStamp table (Id int, SalesMan_ID int, Module_Code
 varchar(50),Time_In varchar(10),Time_Out varchar(10))

Insert into @TimeStamp values
(1,13524,'Analysis','1:30pm','1:40pm'),
(2,12543,'Analysis','2:10pm','2:30pm'),
(3,12543,'Analysis','3:10pm','3:30pm')
```

First expected table output

```
select *From (
Select Row_Number() over (Order By Time_In,SalesMan_id,Seq) id
      ,SalesMan_id
      ,b.Module_Code
      ,Time_In
      ,Time_Out
      ,row_number() over (partition by SalesMan_Id,B.Module_code order by id) as rn
 from @TimeStamp A
 Join (select *from 
 (values (1,'Photo'),(2,'Survey'),(3,'Merchand'))cteBase(Seq,Module_Code)) B
 on (A.Module_Code='Analysis'))t
 where rn=1
 Order By 1
```

Second expected table output

```
 select *From (
Select Row_Number() over (Order By Time_In,SalesMan_id,Seq) id
      ,SalesMan_id
      ,b.Module_Code
      ,Time_In
      ,Time_Out
      ,row_number() over (partition by SalesMan_Id,B.Module_code order by id desc) as rn
 from @TimeStamp A
 Join (select *from 
 (values (1,'Photo'),(2,'Survey'),(3,'Merchand'))cteBase(Seq,Module_Code)) B
 on (A.Module_Code='Analysis'))t
 where rn=1
 Order By 1
```